# Word for a pane showing fictional characters in columns

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

In the manga/anime world you sometimes come across panes that show some of the characters of a certain manga or anime series arranged into columns. Here are some examples:

[Bleach Gotei 13](http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7900000/bleach-bleach-anime-7994301-1280-800.jpg)

[Bleach Main Characters](http://anime-wallpapers.com/images/800x600/bleach-characters.jpg)

[Steins;Gate Characters](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-qfsT5HYadjs/TnWOUsPXZAI/AAAAAAAAAA0/Syt0Y-msRi4/s1600/Steins%253BGate+_3.jpg)

Is there a technical term for such panes? The closest word I can think of is "character roster", but those usually arrange the characters in a grid, rather than in columns.

Comment: maybe ask on [anime.se]?

Comment: Found the word I was looking for, it's [triptych](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tryptych).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any proper  manga or anime terms.  But you might consider calling those layouts character [capsules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_comics_terminology#Encapsulation), character slices, or character [mini-flashbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga_iconography#Panel_characteristics).